# Angular 6 and asp.net mvc core 2.1 identity server 4 "Http failure response for https://localhost:55350/api/account/user: 401 OK"

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, angular6, identityserver4

I am developing an application in Asp.net MVC core 2.1 with the help of Identity server 4 and angular 6.
My application is built on the bases of Identity Server 4.  Application works perfectly when I successfully logged in to the application. All operations and features are working perfectly after logged in.
Now I need to add a Registration form to save the new users through my application.
I have added the form and allow to access the registration form without performing login credentials. 
Now when I perform a submit operation , my application is throwing an exception due to the httpheader . May be I am not defining the header properly or may be there is some restriction on the server side but I am removed all authorization filters from that method/function.

this is the exception :
"Http failure response for https://localhost:55350/api/account/registercartuser: 401 OK"

my tried client side (typescript) functions are:

```
protected getRequestHeadersWithoutOAuth(): { headers: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; } } {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      //'Accept': `application/vnd.iman.v${EndpointFactory.apiVersion}+json, application/json, text/plain, */*`,
      //'App-Version': ConfigurationService.appVersion
    });


 getRegisterUserEndpoint<T>(userObject: any): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.post<T>(this.registerCartUserUrl, JSON.stringify(userObject),
      this.getRequestHeadersWithoutOAuth()).pipe<T>(
      catchError(error => {
        return this.handleErrorWithoutReLogin(error, () => this.getRegisterUserEndpoint(userObject));
      }));
  }


  registerUser(user: UserEdit) {
    return this.accountEndpoint.getRegisterUserEndpoint<User>(user);
  }  


public save() {

    if (!this.form.submitted) {
      this.form.onSubmit(null);
      return;
    }

    if (!this.userProfileForm.valid) {
      this.alertService.showValidationError();
      return;
    }
    const userObj = this.getUser();

      this.userService.saveUser(userObj).subscribe(
        user => this.saveCompleted(user),
        error => this.saveFailed(error));

  }
Server Side function :
        [HttpPost("registercartuser")]        
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterCartUser([FromBody] UserEditViewModel user)
        {
            if (user.Roles == null || (user.Roles != null && user.Roles.Count() == 0))
            {
                if (!(await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(this.User, UserTypes.CartUser.ToString().ToLower(),
                    Authorization.Policies.ViewRoleByRoleNamePolicy)).Succeeded)
                    return new ChallengeResult();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!(await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(this.User,
                    Tuple.Create(user.Roles, new string[] { }),
                    Authorization.Policies.AssignAllowedRolesPolicy)).Succeeded)
                    return new ChallengeResult();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (user == null)
                    return BadRequest($"{nameof(user)} cannot be null");


                ApplicationUser appUser = Mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(user);

                var result = await _accountManager.CreateUserAsync(appUser, user.Roles, user.NewPassword);
                if (result.Item1)
                {
                    UserViewModel userVM = await GetUserViewModelHelper(appUser.Id);
                    return CreatedAtAction(GetUserByIdActionName, new { id = userVM.Id }, userVM);
                }

                AddErrors(result.Item2);
            }

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
internal class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            // Check for authorize attribute
            var hasAuthorize = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .Union(context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
                .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
                .Any();

            if (hasAuthorize)
            {
                operation.Responses.Add("401", new Response { Description = "Unauthorized" });

                operation.Security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
                {
                    new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                    {
                        { "oauth2", new [] { IdentityServerConfig.ApiName} }
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Did you forget `Bearer` in this line?  `'Authorization': 'Bearer'  +  'my-auth-token'`

Comment: Hi Samuel Roberto, thank you for replying. Yes i have forgotten this but i have now tried with it and getting same error . 
alert.service.ts:149 Severity: "error", Summary: "Save Error", Detail: "One or more errors occured whilst saving your changes:", Error: "{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":401,"statusText":"OK","url":"https://localhost:55350/api/account/registercartuser","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for https://localhost:44350/api/account/registercartuser: 401 OK","error":null}

Comment: Thank you very much guys.  I have found the solution of my issue. i was missing the attribute  [AllowAnonymous] on that method/function. now its working